# Permission denied (publickey) - in setting up Kubernetes cluster with Kubespray

Tags: ssh, ansible, ping

This issue is from the following documentation [How to deploy Kubernetes using Kubespray](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/deploy-kubernetes-using-kubespray/). I followed their documentation word by word and reached at this point:

`ansible -i inventory.ini -m ping all`

[Here is the above command in the documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qwtg1.png)

The documentation outlines all the necessary steps on deploying Kubernetes to UpCloud using Kubespray and Terraform. As mentioned earlier, I could execute all the commands until hitting the command: `ansible -i inventory.ini -m ping all`

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/summer/.ssh/id_rsa':
kubespray-worker-2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '<IP address>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nubuntu@<IP address>: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}

Enter passphrase for key '/home/summer/.ssh/id_rsa':
kubespray-worker-0 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '<IP address>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nConnection closed by <IP address> port 22",
    "unreachable": true
}

Enter passphrase for key '/home/summer/.ssh/id_rsa':
kubespray-worker-1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '<IP address>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nubuntu@<IP address>: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
kubespray-master-0 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added '<IP address>' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nubuntu@<IP address>: Permission denied (publickey).",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

[the above error in image form for further reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UULRR.jpg)

**Please note: The region hidden in white inks are the Public IP addresses assigned to each node in the image above**.

I am able to remotely access the Ubuntu server by hitting: `ssh <username>@<ip_address>`. Here is a snapshot of `cluster-settings.tfvars` to see if I have messed-up something:

```
zone     = "fe-fxfx"
username = "ubuntu"

# Prefix to use for all resources to separate them from other resources
prefix = "kubespray"

inventory_file = "inventory.ini"

#  Set the operating system using UUID or exact name
template_name = "Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

ssh_public_keys = [
  # Put your public SSH key here
  "removed the Public Key for security reasons",
]
```

Also, the image from `cluster-settings,tfvars` file for reference:
[cluster-settings.tfvars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJnES.jpg)

The result from pinging the nodes are also irregular, in a sense, if `master-0` is successfully pinged at one instance, in the other, none of them gets pinged [when tried again]. While, sometimes `worker-2` is pinged and rest are not.

Comment: Replace the images with text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this issue after consulting a senior mate. First off, the SSH key pair needs to be generated without a passphrase or if you're using one with a passphrase on, just pass this command to disable it:

Run `ssh-keygyen` with `-p` option.

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

I suggest you to do this inside the directory where your SSH key-pair is located or specify it with `-f ~/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa`

If you did the above step correctly, then you'll be prompted to enter the existing passphrase:

```
Enter old passphrase:
```

After that, enter the new passphrase [basically leave it blank] and confirm it:

```
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
```

If successful, you will get the following prompt:

```
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

**Note:** These steps can be used to remove or change the passphrase.

**Next**
Inside the `cluster-settings.tfvars` file, there are two places with `"enter your SSH key here"` option to enter your public keys. It is not mandatory to enter in both. In my case, I used only one of the public keys and also made sure the key pair was available in SSH agent.